# Configuring Data and Voice VLAN Cisco SG300

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, trunk, voice

I have a Cisco SG300 managed switch I am attempting to configure to handle two VLANs one for data (VLAN1) and another for voice (VLAN20).

Ports 1 and 52 are configured to trunk to the router/firewall, and to a second SG300 switch, respectively.

The remaining ports 2-48 on both switches are set to access mode with access allowing for VLAN20.

However, default VLAN1 traffic is not passing through the port. How can I allow for both VLAN1 and VLAN20 traffic to be used by the remaining ports? Each of the remaining ports will have Cisco and Polycom phones daisy-chained to a PC. The PCs will have no tagged VLANs, phones will have VLAN20.

```
vlan database
vlan 20
exit
voice vlan id 20
voice vlan oui-table add 0001e3 Siemens_AG_phone________
voice vlan oui-table add 00036b Cisco_phone_____________
voice vlan oui-table add 00096e Avaya___________________
voice vlan oui-table add 000fe2 H3C_Aolynk______________
voice vlan oui-table add 0060b9 Philips_and_NEC_AG_phone
voice vlan oui-table add 00d01e Pingtel_phone___________
voice vlan oui-table add 00e075 Polycom/Veritel_phone___
voice vlan oui-table add 00e0bb 3Com_phone______________
hostname HHSSW02
username Admin password encrypted 69a3ff8b0f977aab794acfdd3bbf5fae926b6c2f privilege 15
power inline traps enable
ip ssh server
snmp-server community access1grapher ro view Default
snmp-server host 192.168.1.254 traps version 2c access1grapher
clock timezone CST -6
clock source sntp
sntp unicast client enable
sntp unicast client poll
sntp server time-a.timefreq.bldrdoc.gov poll
ip telnet server
!
interface vlan 1
 ip address 192.168.100.5 255.255.255.0
 no ip address dhcp
!
interface gigabitethernet1
 description FIREWALL
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 20
 power inline priority high
!
interface gigabitethernet2
 switchport mode access vlan 20
 power inline priority high
!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have VLAN 1 allowed on interface 1.

And you have VLAN 20 specified on interface 2. You need to specify VLAN 1, and specify `voice vlan enable`

Comment: When I attempt to apply VLAN1 to any interface, it removed VLAN20 and does not show VLAN 1 in the config. Would this be because it is the default VLAN?

Comment: Also, I get "access mode prevents executing voice enable...

Comment: I switched it to general mode and it lets me apply the command, but how does general mode differ in this case from access?

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with the SG line. From my reading, it appears that `switchport mode general` sets the native vlan to 1, and then `switchport general allowed vlan add 20 tagged` allows the phones to communicate on VLAN 20. This is just a guess, though.